# Javascript Disable button until 3 or more input fields have a value

Tags: javascript

I have 6 input fields in my html page like so:

```
<div class='inputBox'>
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <div>
                <label>Angle of A = </label>
                <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="A" type="number">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Angle of B = </label>
                <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="B" type="text">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Angle of C = </label>
                <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="C" type="text">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Side Length of a = </label>
                <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="a" type="text">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Side Length of b = </label>
                <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="b" type="text">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Side Length of c = </label>
                <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="c" type="text">
            </div>

            <div>
                <button id='calculate' disabled="true" class='field' type="submit">Calculate</button>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

I would like the button to be disabled until any 3 out of the 6 fields have a value. Here is my javascript code:

```
        function enableButton()
        {
            var filled = 0;
            var fields = [...document.getElementsByClassName("field")];
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                if (fields[i].length() > 0)
                {
                    filled += 1;
                }
            }
            if (filled >= 3)
            {
                document.getElementById("calculate").disabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("calculate").disabled = true;
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately the button stays disabled despite the number of fields that have a value.

Comment: `.length()` is not a function, it's a plain property - always check your console for error messages before asking why things aren't working as expected

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am running my application through flask and I did not get a console error.

Comment: If the JavaScript gets run, it will most definitely throw an error

Comment: May I suggest making this a runnable snippet using the code snippet editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a change event to the input fields, I have used `onkeyup` function to invoke the `enableButton` function. Instead of checking `fields[i].length()` try to check whether `fields[i].value` exist or not. Here is a working sample.

```js
function enableButton() {
  var filled = 0;
  var fields = [...document.getElementsByClassName("field")];
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if (fields[i].value) {
      filled += 1;
    }
  }
  if (filled >= 3) {
    document.getElementById("calculate").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("calculate").disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='inputBox'>
  <form action="/" method="post">
    <div>
      <label>Angle of A = </label>
      <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="A" type="number" onkeyup="enableButton()">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Angle of B = </label>
      <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="B" type="text" onkeyup="enableButton()">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Angle of C = </label>
      <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="C" type="text" onkeyup="enableButton()">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Side Length of a = </label>
      <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="a" type="text" onkeyup="enableButton()">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Side Length of b = </label>
      <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="b" type="text" onkeyup="enableButton()">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Side Length of c = </label>
      <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="c" type="text" onkeyup="enableButton()">
    </div>

    <div>
      <button id='calculate' disabled="true" class='field' type="submit">Calculate</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The first input-field doesn't count at your solution the other 5 works ok.

Comment: `Sorry` for my last post, that's only if the first input-field is not valid (if it's not a number) and that is a acceptable solution .

Comment: @Sascha Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

that ?

I just added an id on the form element, and transformed the Id attribute of the button into name, so that I only have the for to declare as const

and also remove all unnecessary divs in the form, light code is always easier to read

```js
const myForm   = document.getElementById('my-form')
  ,   inFields = [...myForm.querySelectorAll('input.field')]
  ;
myForm.oninput=()=>
  {
  let count = inFields.reduce((a,c)=>a+=(c.value.trim().length >0)?1:0,0)
  myForm.calculate.disabled = (count <3)
  }
myForm.onreset=()=>
  {
  myForm.calculate.disabled = true
  }
```

```css
label, input, button { display: block; float: left; margin: .3em; }
label, button:first-of-type { clear: both; }
label { width: 10em; line-height: 2.3em; text-align: right; }
```

```html
<form action="/" method="post" id="my-form">
  <label>Angle of A = </label>
  <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="A" type="number">

  <label>Angle of B = </label>
  <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="B" type="text">

  <label>Angle of C = </label>
  <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="C" type="text">

  <label>Side Length of a = </label>
  <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="a" type="text">

  <label>Side Length of b = </label>
  <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="b" type="text">

  <label>Side Length of c = </label>
  <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="c" type="text">

  <button type="reset">reset</button>
  <button name='calculate' disabled="true" class='field' type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. OP wants `button to be disabled until any 3 out of the 6 fields have a value.` but you enable it when only 1 input field is filled.

Comment: @Sascha you're right; I changed my code... (thoughtlessness on my part)

Comment: No problem, we all make faults. For example I first hided the button instead of disabling it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am going to go with Nitheesh's code as it is more simple and easier for me to understand

Answer (score -1):

You might've had a few problems with that function, but the main problem is that you never call the `enableButton` function. The code below calls it whenever one of the fields are changed.

```js
function enableButton() {
  let filled = 0;
  let fields = document.getElementsByClassName("field");
  for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    if (fields[i].value != "") {
      filled++;
    }
  }
  if (filled > 2) {
    document.getElementById("calculate").removeAttribute("disabled");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("calculate").setAttribute("disabled", "");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='inputBox'>
  <form action="/" method="post">
    <div>
      <label>Angle of A = </label>
      <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="A" type="number" onchange="enableButton()">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Angle of B = </label>
      <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="B" type="text" onchange="enableButton()">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Angle of C = </label>
      <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="C" type="text" onchange="enableButton()">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Side Length of a = </label>
      <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="a" type="text" onchange="enableButton()">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Side Length of b = </label>
      <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="b" type="text" onchange="enableButton()">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Side Length of c = </label>
      <input class='field' autocomplete="off" autofocus name="c" type="text" onchange="enableButton()">
    </div>

    <div>
      <button id='calculate' type="submit" disabled>Calculate</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The first input-field doesn't count at your solution the other 5 works ok.

Comment: `Sorry` for my last post, that's only if the first input-field is not valid (if it's not a number) and that is a acceptable solution

Comment: Thanks! I like your solution too.

Answer (score -1):

How did you call the function , also put a console log to check if the function is getting called. also as @certainPerformance told .length is a property not an function